# Background image not appearing from the top CSS

Tags: html, css, image, navbar

`There is a gap above the top of the image. What is causing it? I want the image to appear from the very top of the page. The image covers takes up half the width of the webpage.`

> The HTML (Here I have added a navbar and there is a div tag which consists an image.)

```
<nav class="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href ="#home"><div class ="line-effect">Home</div></a></li>
        <li><a href ="#about"><div class="line-effect">About</div></a></li>
        <li><a href ="#portfolio"><div class="line-effect">Portfolio</div></a></li>
    </ul>   
</nav>


<div class="bg-image">
    <img src="newvec.png"  height="800px" width="750px">
</div>
```

> The CSS (This is the styling for the navbar. There is no style applied to the image. The "box:sizing:border-box" property has been applied to the whole document.)

```
   .navbar{
    padding:5px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
    position:fixed;
    padding:50px 10px;
    width:100%;
    height:8vh;  
    }

  .navbar ul{
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 20px 40px; 
    }

   .navbar ul li a{
    font-family: Nunito;
    color:black;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 25px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you checked your `<body>` tag?
If you didn't used `reset.css` there is standard `margin` in `<body>` tag.

Just try to add

```
body {
  margin : 0;
}
```

on your css tag.